# Selenium Webdriver - unable to click on button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML code:

```
<div class="buttonBG">  
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='?mod=eA&amp;act=00001';"        class="buttonGreen" value="TK">         
<input type="button" onclick="ttoggle('carianDiv');" class="buttonGreen"   value="CK"> 
</div>
```

Below is my java code, when I try with below code. Can I know whats wrong is in my selenium webdriver code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='buttonGreen' and  contains(@onclick, 'window.location.href='?mod=eA&act=00001')]")).click();
```

Comment: This is missing  HTML CODE -                                                             <div class="buttonBG"> 
<input type="button" value="TK" class="buttonGreen" onclick="window.location.href='?mod=eA&amp;act=00001';">   
<input type="button" value="CK" class="buttonGreen" onclick="ttoggle('CKdiv');"> 
</div>

Comment: What is the error message you got? Share you share your error message or few lines from you HTML?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[value='TK']"}
Command duration or timeout: 5.03 seconds

Comment: Thank you guys for reply I got answer . My div is within iFrame so first i switch to iframe then it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to search by value

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='TK']")).click();
```

And for what's wrong, you are searching for `?mod=eA&act=00001` when in the html its

`?mod=eA&amp;act=00001`

> Edit

Another solution is to insert the buttons to list and click by index:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.className("buttonGreen"));
buttons.get(0).click();
```

You can also try using explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[value='TK']")).click();
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the button to be visible before clicking on it. You can change the selector or time span.

Comment: guy Its not working .  i tried with your changes but it still not working.

Comment: @Sandeep I added another solution

Comment: Thank you guy for reply I got answer . My div is within iFrame so first i switch to iframe then it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using XPath instead of CSS

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@onclick=\'window.location.href=\'?mod=eA&amp;act=00001\';\']').click()
```

Edit

**Here is the code to switch to iFrame,**

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name");
```

**NOTE**: After completing the operation inside the iframe, you have to again return back to the main window using the following command.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: thank you for reply I got answer . My div is within iFrame so first i switch to iframe then it work for me.